# How change pod restart policy

Tags: kubernetes

How to change the restart policy of a running pod from `Always` to `Never`. I've `kubectl edit` but it does not allow to change it.

Comment: Can you please attach exactly your kubectl edit command and your yaml/json file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `kubectl edit` is not allowing you to change the `restartPolicy`

Do this,
`kubectl delete deployment <deployment_name>`

Edit yaml file with new changes.
Then create deployment again.
`kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`

**Or**

Edit yaml file with new changes.
and apply changes to deployment using.
`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

This will delete old pod and will create new pod with new changes.

Answer (score 3):

Once you created the pod, kubernetes makes some properties immutable. These are mostly the options which can change pods stability, for example this.

You can get the manifest using `kubectl get pod $PODNAME -o yaml --export`. Then edit this manifest and change the restartPolicy field to Never and redeploy it.

Comment: Thanks for posting. The simplest solution in my case was deleting the deployment associated with the pod `kubectl delete deployment <name>`

Comment: Deleting a deployment will result in service disruption, replacing pods after patching the deployment will not result in service disruption.

Answer (score 0):

If  you have pods associated with deployemnt edit it setting up proper restartPolicy for your pod.

`$ kubectl edit your_deployment_name`

Save changes, delete old pod, new one will come with proper resartPolicy.

To see the rollout status, run:

`$ kubectl rollout status your_deployment_name`

Read more here: [pods-restart-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/), [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

Deleting pod doesn't change anything if you don't change manifest of deployment and add proper restartPolicy.

You can also delete whole deployment, change configuration file and create it from scratch.